# Specifying linear regression in python

Tags: python, statistics, regression

I tried to implement robust standard errors to my linear regression, but received the following error:
`LinAlgError: Singular matrix`

Here is the code that raises the error:

```
#Get robust standard errors
Robust=sm.OLS(y,X, M=sm.robust.norms.HuberT()).fit()
Robust.summary()
qq = sm.qqplot(Robust.resid, line = 'r') 
Robust2=sm.RLM(y,X, M=sm.robust.norms.HuberT()).fit(cov="H2")
Robust2.summary()
shapiro(residual)

pred_val2 = Robust2.fittedvalues.copy()
true_val = regression_data_performance['CRSP_return_p1'].values.copy()
residual2 = true_val - pred_val2
shapiro(residual2)


data=['Sales','up_revision','pos_EPS','filing_range','time','DebttoAssets','ShareOverhang','VentureBacked','CRSP_ret_SP500_prior30days',
           'CRSP_vola_SP500_prior30days','top_tier_dummy','ProceedsAmtInThisMktMil','Age','MainSICCode_industry48_y_Soda',
    'MainSICCode_industry48_y_PerSv','MainSICCode_industry48_y_Rtail','MainSICCode_industry48_y_Rubbr','MainSICCode_industry48_y_Ships',
    'MainSICCode_industry48_y_Smoke','MainSICCode_industry48_y_Steel','MainSICCode_industry48_y_Toys','MainSICCode_industry48_y_Txtls','MainSICCode_industry48_y_Whlsl','CRSP_return_p1']


regression_data_performance=regression_data_performance[~isNaN(regression_data_performance['filing_range'])]
data=regression_data_performance[data]
data1=data.fillna(0)
data2 = preprocessing.scale(data1)
```

In case it helps you here is the complete error message:

```
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-1febd940375c> in <module>
      3 Robust.summary()
      4 qq = sm.qqplot(Robust.resid, line = 'r')
----> 5 Robust2=sm.RLM(y,X, M=sm.robust.norms.HuberT()).fit(cov="H2")
      6 Robust2.summary()
      7 shapiro(residual)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\robust\robust_linear_model.py in fit(self, maxiter, tol, scale_est, init, cov, update_scale, conv, start_params)
    299             converged = _check_convergence(criterion, iteration, tol, maxiter)
    300         results = RLMResults(self, wls_results.params,
--> 301                              self.normalized_cov_params, self.scale)
    302 
    303         history['iteration'] = iteration

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\robust\robust_linear_model.py in __init__(self, model, params, normalized_cov_params, scale)
    410         self.data_in_cache = ['sresid']
    411 
--> 412         self.cov_params_default = self.bcov_scaled
    413         # TODO: "pvals" should come from chisq on bse?
    414 

pandas\_libs\properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.CachedProperty.__get__()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\robust\robust_linear_model.py in bcov_scaled(self)
    453             W = np.dot(model.M.psi_deriv(self.sresid) * model.exog.T,
    454                        model.exog)
--> 455             W_inv = np.linalg.inv(W)
    456             # [W_jk]^-1 = [SUM(psi_deriv(Sr_i)*x_ij*x_jk)]^-1
    457             # where Sr are the standardized residuals

<__array_function__ internals> in inv(*args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in inv(a)
    545     signature = 'D->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'd->d'
    546     extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_singular)
--> 547     ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
    548     return wrap(ainv.astype(result_t, copy=False))
    549 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag)
     95 
     96 def _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag):
---> 97     raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
     98 
     99 def _raise_linalgerror_nonposdef(err, flag):

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Does anyone know how I can solve the error? If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: The traceback means that the weighted design matrix is singular. Check whether your design matrix, X, is singular, i.e. has collinear columns. If not, then it could be that the weights for robustness removes observation and the left over design matrix is singular.

Comment: @Josef Thanks for your answer, but that does not really help me. Do you know some literature or so where I can find more information?